# Pointer to deallocated variable changes address

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, object-lifetime

This code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* fun()
{
    int a = 5;
    int* pointerA = &a;

    cout << pointerA << endl;

    return pointerA;
}

int main()
{

    int* p = fun();

    cout << p << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints the following:

```
0x[some address]
0
```

---

I understand that the variable `a` is deallocated when the function `fun()` returns, but why does `cout << p << endl;` return 0? Shouldn't it still point to the same address in memory, even though variable is technically not there anymore? Is this a compiler feature or undefined behavior?

[repro case](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I5LRpUCWcA4mL0YO)

EDIT: I found the culprit. I am using CodeBlocks, and in this project's build options, there is a flag "optimize even more (for speed) [-O2]". If it is checked, I get `0`, and if I uncheck the flag, I get the same address `0x[some address]`, which is expected behavior.

I apologize for not mentioning my IDE.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this behavior on macOS with clang 10.0.1 nor on Linux with gcc 6.3.

Comment: Interesting, doesn't happen on debug only on release builds. I thought it'd be the other way around.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: *Shouldn't it still point to the same address in memory, even though variable is technically not there anymore?* -- The compiler's optimizer does amazing things when you write stuff like this, agree?  You know it's code that may not work, but at the same time you're saying "it should work".

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/I5LRpUCWcA4mL0YO here is the repro case

Comment: Which means that somewhere this code _is_ in fact UB, otherwise the optimizer wouldn't be allowed to optimize this.

Comment: Returning a pointer to a local variable and then accessing such pointer is undefined behavior.  It doesn't matter how benign the access of the pointer may be -- the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie UB is only accessing the value it points to (which is not in case here).

Comment: Tempted to post a question for the general case.

Comment: @VTT from [basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]: `The effect of using an invalid pointer value
(including passing it to a deallocation function) is undefined.` Does "using an invalid pointer value" not include OP's case?

Comment: I found the solution, check the OP's post.

Comment: @kakkoko The quoted block seems to be from notes, which are non-normative. And the wording is rather strange. I mean if accessing even  the *object representation* of the invalid pointer is UB then using null pointers in any form would be UB as well which makes no sense.

Comment: @VTT Sorry, I was looking at an old standard. In C++14, this part was changed to `Any other use of
an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.`

Comment: @user3007875 That's not a solution, it just removes the optimized code from UB.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Solution is that compiler optimizes pointer to null, when local variable that said pointer pointed to, is deallocated. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Yes that's correct but the interesting part would be where the standard says its UB

Comment: _Shouldn't it still point to the same address in memory_ Meaningless question. Invalid pointer values do not represent addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the return value of `fun` has implementation-defined behavior, as it returns an invalid pointer value (see the quote below, why). In particular platforms, it may even generate a runtime fault. So, `p`'s value is implementation-defined as well. Most likely, it will became invalid pointer value, so accessing it is implementation-defined.

[basic.std/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#4):

> When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the values of all pointers representing the address of any part of that region of storage become invalid pointer values. Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior. **Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior**.

Comment: Which part of the std requires the impl to document the behavior?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a compiler feature. In this case it is very easy to see that the pointer returned by fun will be invalid and thus further usage of the pointer will result in undefined behaviour. If you try a different compiler it might be different. E.g. for me in Visual Studio 2012 it does return the actual address instead of 0.